# Least squares system identification gives wrong coefficients

Tags: linear-model, matlab, identifiability

I am working on  system identification using least squares method.  I implemented the algorithm as recommended by the original paper.
This [link](http://wikis.controltheorypro.com/Offline_Least_Squares) describes what I implemented.

Example of desired model to identify where `y` is the estimated output, `u` the input and `n` the error:

$$
\hat{y}(z) = \frac{b_0 + b_1 z^{-1}}{1 + a_1 z^{-1} + a_2 z^{-2}} u(z) + n(z)
$$

So far this is my implementation in matlab:

```
function [ Parameters ] = LMS2( n,m,Data,DataInput,sample )

outputs=Data(1:sample,2);                            
inputs=DataInput(1:sample,2)
inputs=awgn(inputs,40);%Add white noise to input signal
k=max(n,m);
s=size(inputs);

datasize=s(1,1);
Ap=inputs(k:datasize,1);
y=outputs(k:datasize,1);
for i=1:m
 Ap=[Ap,inputs(k-i:datasize-i,1)] ;
 inputs(k-i,1)
end

for i=0:n-1
 Ap=[Ap,outputs(k-i:datasize-i,1)] ;
end    

rank(Ap)
Parameters=inv(Ap'*Ap)*Ap'*y;
```

The function below takes as parameters `n` the denominator degree, `m` the numerator degree, `Data` the output matrix and `DataInput` the input matrix. `sample` is the number of rows we want to use for the system identification.
I used as inputs step, sinusoid and ramp.  Problem is the numerator coefficients are always set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting in regressor matrix `Ap` with the same lag for both `inputs` and `outputs`:

- `inputs` should start from `k+1`
- `outputs` should start from `k`
- `y` should start from `k+1`

Corrected version:

```matlab
datasize=s(1,1);
Ap=inputs(k+1:datasize);
y=outputs(k+1:datasize);

for i=1:m-1
 Ap=[Ap,inputs(k+1-i:datasize-i,1)] ;
 inputs(k-i,1)
end

for i=0:n-1
 Ap=[Ap,outputs(k-i:datasize-i-1,1)] ;
end    

rank(Ap)
Parameters=pinv(Ap)*y;
```